# Custom Content Element Tab not showing for editor users

Tags: extbase, typo3-11.x

I am dealing with a strange issue after the update to Typo3 11.5.

My extension adds several content elements to the new content element wizard in its own tab.

What does not work:
Users do not see the custom tab in the new content element wizard

What works:
Admins can see the tab in the content element wizard
Users can edit the elements once they are created
Users can change the type of an element to any of the custom elements using the "Type" dropdown

So, users seem to have all the access rights they need (confirmed in backend group settings).
The wizard seems to be configured correctly (confirmed accessing as admin).

But only admins see the tab.
If you have any hint what I could look into, I would be very grateful.
Below is the .tsconfig file I use for the wizard:

```
mod.wizards {
    newContentElement.wizardItems {
        abc.header = ABC
        abc.elements {    
            abc_slider {
                iconIdentifier = abc
                title = ABC Slider
                description = ABC Slider
                tt_content_defValues {
                    CType = abc_slider
                    list_type = abc_slider
                }
            }
        }       
    }
    
    newContentElement.wizardItems {
        abc.header = ABC
        abc.elements {    
            abc_text {
                iconIdentifier = abc
                title = ABC Text
                description = ABC Text
                tt_content_defValues {
                    CType = abc_text
                    list_type = abc_text
                }
            }
        }       
    }   
}
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.abc.show = *
```

I have tried adding more permissions to the backend user, but they already had rights to all elements and there was no permission setting for the tab.
I have tried adding settings to the tsconfig of the backend user and backend user group, but that did not have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem by removing the **list_type** lines from above configuration. I still need to look into what other potential consequences this might have, but I noticed in the Info > PageTSConfig that the other elements only had a CType, not a list_type.

Using Jafix's comment about the addToList method, I added one of my elements to the "Common" tab. Again, the admin user found it there, but the editor user did not. If I renamed the Common tab, that would show for the editor user, so there was at least some effect of the configuration.

I am speculating that my users would need permission to "list_type slider" and not only to "CType slider", but the backend did not offer this. For now, just removing "list_type" did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/ContentElementsWizard.html#add-your-plugin-or-content-element-to-a-different-tab) says `show = *` is for the plugins-tab. I had success using the documented way. So your code should look like this:

```
mod.wizards {
    newContentElement.wizardItems {
        abc.header = ABC
        abc.elements {    
            abc_slider {
                iconIdentifier = abc
                title = ABC Slider
                description = ABC Slider
                tt_content_defValues {
                    CType = abc_slider
                    list_type = abc_slider
                }
            }
        }
        abc.show := addToList(abc_slider)
    }
    
    newContentElement.wizardItems {
        abc.elements {    
            abc_text {
                iconIdentifier = abc
                title = ABC Text
                description = ABC Text
                tt_content_defValues {
                    CType = abc_text
                    list_type = abc_text
                }
            }
        }
        abc.show := addToList(abc_text)     
    }   
}
```

Comment: The way I understood that part of the documentation is:
abs.show := addToList(abc_text) means add one element to the abc tab which is very useful if you want to add an element to for example the "common" tab.

mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.abc.show = *
add all of the above to the abc tab which is what I wanted. Both configurations work, using the * requires less code and good if you are the creator of the abc tab.

Both "work" for the admin users, but not for the editors.
But, I found out that the problem was with the list_type setting and will answer my question now.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say thank you!
The addToList method did not solve the problem, but it helped me run some more tests.